# ayuda con checkbox

Tags: php, javascript

buenas soy estoy aprendiendo y me gustaría que me ayuden con un checkbox de bootstrap switch 
quiero que cuando seleccione no tenga un valor de cero y cuando seleccione si tenga un valos de 1 estube investigando pero no he podido dar con la solucion

este es el checkbox

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Requiere Imei/Numero:</label>
                <div class="form-check form-check-switch form-check-switch-left">
                  <label class="form-check-label d-flex align-items-center">
                    <input id="imei" name="imei"  type="checkbox" data-off-color="success" data-on-color="danger"  data-on-text="No" data-off-text="Si" class="form-check-input-switch" checked>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>


<script >

$('#imei').bootstrapSwitch();

</script>
```

como puedo hacerlo estoy usando el bootstrap switch v3.3.4. 
cuando esta en no envia un value **on** y cuando esta en si no manda value

Comment: ¿Me puedes decir el link de la librería que ocupas exactamente?

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es capturar con javascript la clase de tu checkbox.

```
 <input id="imei" name="imei"  type="checkbox" data-off-color="success" data-on-color="danger"  data-on-text="No" data-off-text="Si" class="form-check-input-switch nombredetuclaseaqui" checked>
```

notesé que en la propiedad **class** agregué la clase **nombredetuclaseaqui**

luego con javascript o jquery puedes capturar si te da verdadero o falso con:

```
document.querySelector()
```

lo guardas dentro de una variable:

```
var micheckbox = document.querySelector('.nombredetuclaseaqui');
```

y luego creas una condicional:

```
if(micheckbox.checked == true){ var seleccioncheckbox = '1'}
if(micheckbox.checked == false){ var seleccioncheckbox = '0'}
```

luego esa variable la puedes usar para enviarla en una petición ajax.

Cualquier consulta, me dices  :).